# Tensorflow docker image not building PointPillars

Tags: docker, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

- Autoware version : 1.12.0
- ROS Version Melodic
- Autoware installed from Docker
- Docker version 19.03.2, build  6a30dfc

I want to use `PointPillars` but it is not built when during the docker image build and I have this message in the log :

> 8942 Starting >>> lidar_shape_estimation

> 8943 ^[[91m--- stderr: lidar_point_pillars

> 8944 CUDA is available!

> 8945 CUDA Libs: /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart_static.a;-lpthread;dl;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so

> 8946 CUDA Headers: /usr/local/cuda/include

> 8947 TensorRT is NOT Available

> 8948 CUDNN is NOT Available

> 8949 PointPillars won't be built, CUDA and/or TensorRT were not found.

> 8950 ---

> 8951 ^[[0mFinished <<< lidar_point_pillars [5.09s]

So it seems that CUDNN and TensorRT are missing, Do you know if I missed something during the docker build or if I need to build autoware from source directly ?

Thanks a lot !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336749/tensorflow-docker-image-not-building-pointpillars/) by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2019-11-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Mackou The reason it is not building in our Docker image is because the CUDA image does not have CuDNN or TensorRT, only CUDA. You will have to create your own Docker image using ours as a base if you wish to add CuDNN and TensorRT. Building from source on your machine with these installed would be another alternative.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2019-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on 2019-12-05**:
Thanks for your answer !
I have contributed to the autoware docker repo and cuda and tensorrt should be available in the docker container in version 1.14 ! :)

**Comment by [ThomasL624](https://answers.ros.org/users/50229/thomasl624/) on 2019-12-12**:
cuDNN and TensorRT are available in version 1.14 or 1.13?
From the release announcement, the Dockerfile latest-melodic-CUDA stated that added cuDNN and TensorRT. So, are those ready or not?

**Comment by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on 2019-12-12**:
@ThomasL624

It will be available in version 1.14. But you can already use the master branch to get cuDNN and TensorRT.

**Comment by [ThomasL624](https://answers.ros.org/users/50229/thomasl624/) on 2019-12-13**:
Sorry i am a bit new to autoware, from wt you mean, is that cuDNN and TensorRT are available, however, the pointpillars function is not published in 1.13version, am i right? As i got a error msg that pointpillars is not a launch file sth like that. thank you

**Comment by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on 2019-12-16**:
@ThomasL624 Not exactly.

I am talking about the docker version. Pointpillars is present in 1.13 **but is not working**

Pointpillars **will work in version 1.14** if you use the docker version.

**Version 1.14 is not yet available**

If you want to have the "beta" version of the 1.14 you can clone the **master** branch of the autoware docker repo here : https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/docker